# React Jest import immutable object not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, immutable.js

I'm new to Jest and React and is setting up Jest unit test for the React web project and encounter this problem when I'm trying to do it on Reducer. 
It seems like when the file being tested contains Record, it becomes undefined when npm test (It is running perfectly when npm start).
I've put jest.unmock('immutable'), jest.autoMockOff() on test.js file, but it seems like not working... digging for solution but I find nothing...

here is the file/output/setting

./reducer.js

```
export const initialState = new Record({ ... })()
...
export default function reducer(state=initialState, action) {...}
```

./__test__/reducer.test.js

```
import reducer,{initialState} from '../reducer'
describe('reducer',()=>{

    it('initial state',()=>{
        expect(reducer(undefined,{})).toEqual(
            initialState
        )
    })
})
```

npm test output

```
 FAIL  src\reducers\__test__\reducer.test.js

 ● Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: initialState is not defined

  at reducer (src/reducers/reducer.js:88:303)
  at node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:53:24
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at assertReducerShape (node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:51:25)
  at combineReducers (node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:107:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/index.js:34:48)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/configureStore.development.js:19:255)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/configureStore.js:4:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:10:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils.js:11:161)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions/actions.js:373:324)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/reducer.js:64:229)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/__test__/reducer.test.js:7:21)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
"enzyme": "^2.9.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1",
"jest": "^20.0.4",
"jest-immutable-matchers": "^1.5.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-scripts": "^1.0.10",
"react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
"redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
"redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
"redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.1.1",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3"
},
```

.babelrc

```
{
"presets":["react","es2015","stage-0","stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution ? Im facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was able to solve it with two resolutions

1. Include the right babel-presets (remove react-app);

**package.json**

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          "env",
          "react",
          "stage-0"
        ]
      }
    }
```

**dependencies**
`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage0`

2. Ensure my local directory structure doesn't have the same names; for example, my structure was as follows:

`~/sites/project
  @htdocs -> src
  src/ (create-react-app <root>)
    build/
    config/
    src/
      components/
      ...
      index.js
    package.json`

Note that I had 'src' as the root name and also 'src' as the folder containing the react files. For some reason, Immutable Records were complaining about this, so I simply changed one of the 'src' directories to something different (i.e., 'source').

Answer (score 0):

I have created `initialState.js` file for stores and its working file for me. I hope this will help for you.

```
export default {
    // STORE
    stories:{},
}
```

And imported like below

```
import initialState from '../initialState'
```